# MySQL error column cannot be null although default value set

Tags: mysql

I recently moved my SQL Database to another Amazon RDS server with version 5.7.

Before that, the application was working fine but now I started logging errors:

> "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column xyz cannot be null" - The column already has a default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I checked online and people suggested to have the `sql_mode` equal to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

I checked the existing settings and it is already like that.

Any other reason I am getting this error? Any tricks?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you upgrade the mysql version?

Comment: I created a new RDS instance and it is with the latest version of MySQL, so I think yes.

Comment: you might need to pass it manually then

Answer (score 2):

After searching more, the problem was only in timestamp fields with current_timestamp default value. I searched in the parameters and found **explicit_defaults_for_timestamp** that was enabled (value 1) and with a bit more research, I had to disable this parameter as per the documentation here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

in order to get the required result and fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Simply deactivate explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

```
SET GLOBAL explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 0;
```

Comment: Make sure you include this in your my.cnf file to make it persistent.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it works like that in this particular case, so I would concentrate on fixing a problem.

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` has nothing to do with the error, during application run. I would select rows with column "xyz" of `NULL` value and update it to something - not null.

`Default` is applied when row is created. Let's say you have a table with some millions of rows, and want to add column with not null. That would block your table for significant amount of time. So you can create column without not null, but with default. That operation deals only with metadata, so is fast. `Default` will deal with all new rows. After that you can slowly update all rows. At the end not null constraint can be added. Not sure if DB is checking constraint when adding it at last step. Or maybe prev. version had problem with it? With MySQL things like that happens.

Comment: I think I maybe did not explain the problem very well. The column xyz always existed and always had a NOT NULL constraint and always had a default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, there are no rows with NULL value. The application used to insert records to the table and the default value was normally inserted to the field xyz.

I did not change anything in the application, all I did was that I created a dump from the existing database, created a new AWS RDS instance with MySql 5.7.19, imported the dump file. After that whenever the application tries to insert a record in this table, I get this error

Comment: Are you providing column xyz in the insert query? What about the data, maybe there is something strange after reimporting? Just trying to figure our what could go wrong...

Comment: I do not think the problem has to do with the application code, the code was working just fine before the migration. It must be some configuration with the MySql.

Comment: That is also clear to me, however it can be that something was allowed in previous version and is prohibited now... That is why I was asking about putting xyz into insert query. It can be that prev. version applied default when null was passed, and new one just takes null.

Comment: Totally understood and probably is the case since I am using an ORM that is probably doing that, still I don't want to correct 100 instances in the code where this takes place but rather find out what the MySql configuration difference needed to fix this and make it work like before.

Comment: They've changed support for so called - zero date. But that is not your case - error message is different. Can you check who the insert looks like?